# How to remove parent and children records - without using cascade

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using a Db-first approach.

I'm not new to EF, but I cooked up this example because I had become unsure of how to deal with complex parent-child FK situations when deleting. This example serves the purpose, although the code im working on has 10-12 inter-related tables with FK relations, a batch of which needs to get removed.

So when removing records, is the order important in which they are done?  It would in TSQL (need to remove parent records first, then children)

Example below, I get the following error, obviously because Book as a FK to Warehouse
*

Note:

> {"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
> "FK_Book_Warehouse". The conflict occurred in database "AdHoc",
> table "dbo.Book", column 'WarehouseKey'.\r\nThe statement has been
> terminated."}

Also note:

- Cascade will not work if each related entity has to be fetched based on its own query?
- Using joins like this is needed as there will be 100K+ records being removed and a "where/contains" gets messy.
- Would prefer to do this all within ONE savechanges, as to use TransactionScope to wrap it all in a transaction.
- Im using a Db-first workflow and a reverse engineering tool called EF Core POCO generator, so manually adjusting the generated model classes isn't preferred since those changes would get lost when the schema changes and the model is re-generated.

[image]

```
  public bool DeleteComplex()
        {
            bool retval = false;

                string bookfilter = "Big Fish";
    
                // get authors to remove based on book title
                List<Author> AuthorList = (from a in ctx.Book 
                                           join b in ctx.Author on a.AuthorKey equals b.Id where a.Title.Contains(bookfilter) select b).ToList();
                ctx.Author.RemoveRange(AuthorList);
    
                // get warehouses to remove based on book title
                List<Warehouse> WarehouseList = (from a in ctx.Book
                                                 join b in ctx.Warehouse on a.WarehouseKey equals b.Id
                                                 where a.Title.Contains(bookfilter)
                                                 select b).ToList();
                ctx.Warehouse.RemoveRange(WarehouseList);
    
                // remove books based on title
                List<Book> BookList = (from a in ctx.Book where a.Title.Contains(bookfilter) select a).ToList();
                ctx.Book.RemoveRange(BookList);
                int results = ctx.SaveChanges();
                if(results > 0)
                {
                    retval = true;
                }
    
                return retval;
            }
```

**[update working now]**

- The difference is in calling savechanges after first removing a parent (or collection of them as a result of a query), and THEN removing the dependent collections and calling savechanges.  Also, wrapping all this in a transaction lets all go or none.

public bool DeleteComplex()
{
bool retval = false;

```
    string bookfilter = "Big Fish";

    // get books to remove based on title
    List<Book> BookList = (from a in ctx.Book where a.Title.Contains(bookfilter) select a).ToList();


    // get authors to remove based on book title
    List<Author> AuthorList = (from a in ctx.Book
                               join b in ctx.Author on a.AuthorKey equals b.Id
                               where a.Title.Contains(bookfilter)
                               select b).ToList();

    // get warehouses to remove based on book title
    List<Warehouse> WarehouseList = (from a in ctx.Book
                                     join b in ctx.Warehouse on a.WarehouseKey equals b.Id
                                     where a.Title.Contains(bookfilter)
                                     select b).ToList();

    // remove parent first and persist
    ctx.Book.RemoveRange(BookList);
    int results = ctx.SaveChanges();
    if (results > 0)
    {
        retval = true;
    }


    // now remove dependents
    ctx.Author.RemoveRange(AuthorList);
    ctx.Warehouse.RemoveRange(WarehouseList);

    results = ctx.SaveChanges();
    if (results > 0)
    {
        retval = true;
    }
    else
    {
        retval = false;
    }





    return retval;
}

    try
    {
        // test
        //var results = service.GetDoTest();
        //Console.WriteLine(results);
        using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            var results2 = service.DeleteComplex();
            Console.WriteLine(results2);

            transaction.Complete();
        }


    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error($"Ran into error: {ex.ToString()}");
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, what you have shown is exactly the opposite of how it has to be done - child (referencing) records first, then parent (referenced) record. And if this is not SqlServer, or there are no "cycles or multiple cascade paths" in the data relationships, you'd better *use* cascade delete.

Comment: 1) Transaction better to start suing DbContext, you do not have distributed transactions. 2) If you successfully removed books, you do not remove authors and warehouses.